# Root Mean Square value, but with reverse order of operation

Tags: terminology, rms

I've got a question about name of some specific value. Root Mean Square value is defined as such: $$ RMS = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^{N}{x_i^2}} $$
I came across a value, that is similar, but is calculated in "reversed" order, i.e.:
$$ *something* = {\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^{N}\sqrt{|x_i|}\right)}^2 $$
Is there a name for such a value? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Where did you come across this value? Why do you think it is a useful quantity that should have a name? (It doesn't appear at all useful to me.)

Comment: It is a [generalised mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) and (assuming everything is non-negative) lies between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean

Comment: @Henry, your comment looks like a valid answer. Consider posting it as such.

Comment: It's a kind of power mean https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerMean.html  (Personally, I try to reserve the term "generalized mean" for $t^{-1}(\overline{t(x)})$ where $t$ may be something more general still than $x^p$; this would still count as one of those as well, naturally)

Comment: Thank you very much for those comments! I came across it in the definition of the "Clearance factor" - a signal feature used mainly in vibration analysis of bearings. It is defined as: 
$\frac{max|x_i|}{(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sqrt{|x_i|})^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copied from comments:*

It is a [generalised mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) and (assuming everything is non-negative) lies between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean

Comment: It is only equal to a generalised mean if the $x_i$ are all non-negative. The definition of generalised means does not include converting to negative numbers to absolute values, and for good reason because that would invalidate all the theorems that make generalised means useful.

Comment: @GordonSmyth Maybe, or if you prefer: "a generalised mean of the absolute values"

Comment: Sure. But that's a description rather than a name. You're essentially making up a name yourself, whereas my interpretation is that OP was asking whether this quantity had an already existing established name.